# Equivalent of PHP Sessions in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, session

I was going to ask about how to implement sessions in JS,I found few functions that can be used like this example I found :

```
String exforsys = request.getParameter("test"); 
session.setAttribute("test", exforsys);
```

And then just use `session.getAttribute( exforsys);`

But no response, I guess it's only used in servlets or something.

Anyway, I decided that maybe someone has an alternative way other than just use sessions, what am trying to do is click on a link in one page and depending on which link was pressed I will load different information.

Since its a `onclick` function, I'm stuck with JS!

So I need to pass this information to the second page, cookies works well cause it can be handled with both PHP and JS easily but some computers deletes cookies and that wouldn't be nice!

Any suggestions or other ways I can reach what I want but with out using sessions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sessions are server variables. Thus cannot be used by JavaScript.

However, you can retrieve the session variables, through ajax request.

Script (jQuery)

```
//This portion will be triggered once the DOM is loaded and is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("getsession.php",
       { "variable" : "yourneededsessionvariable" }, 
       function(data) {
         //data contains your session data
       }
    );
});
```

PHP

```
//getsession.php
<?PHP
session_start();
echo $_SESSION[$_POST['variable']];
?>
```

Comment: Unless you're extra bored and simply make a small PHP script to be loaded via AJAX to return a JSON representation of the collection of $_SERVER variables!

Comment: @jerluc, I was just suggesting that method. LOL

Comment: :p despite it's simplicity it is a fairly useful utility-type script

Comment: Yeah, if made a simple plugin.. it is definately an utility.

Comment: am trying it but nothing :( 
just to make sure the $.post in my javascript code in the first page and the other one in php! its obvious lol! but why its not working? :(

Comment: It's a jquery code. Make sure you have jquery library included in your page. And the post code, need to be triggered upon certain event. Either $(document).ready() or, $('#link').click();

Comment: I think, you will need this during the page load so, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use  [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp) or client controlled [cookies.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).  Sessions uses server-controlled cookies.  Cookies are just small files that resided on the client.

Comment: There is also session storage to consider (data destroyed on tab being closed).

Answer (score 1):

A session handle is stored in a cookie. If cookies are not accepted, the server will add the sessionID to the URL. If you do not have cookies, you cannot persist anything except in the url.

Why does "onclick" stop you from using sessions? You can ajax things to the server and add them to the session onclick

Answer (score 1):

A session generally means "Some data stored on the server and associated with a user via a token stored in a cookie". You can't do that with client side JavaScript (for obvious reasons).

You could store data directly in a cookie.

If you are willing to sacrifice wide browser support, then you can get increased storage by using one of the client side storage mechanisms introduced by HTML 5 and Friends.

> maybe someone has an alternative way other than just use sessions,what am trying to do is click on a link in one page,and depending on which link was pressed I will load different information.

Just link to *different* pages.

> some computers deletes cookies and that wouldn't be nice

If they delete all cookies, then a session isn't going to work either.

Comment: that was my final solution to link to different pages! 
Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

Append the data you want the next page to get on the query string.

```
<a href="foo.html?bar=123">123</a>
<a href="foo.html?bar=456">456</a>
```

Then on foo.html you can inspect `location.href` to see what was passed in.  THere is no need for cookies here.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server scipring language while javascript is client end language
you cannot literally make sessions in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use request parameters? i.e. `http://yourserver.com/page.php?link=1`

Comment: yeah will work since the data am passing isn't critical at all ! 
thank you

Comment: No problem, though @Starx's method is fairly intuitive as well as a more general-purpose solution.